# Resolution of specific domains is not attempted

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, dns

**Background**: after an extended session of network testing (including crafting packets and changing the interface settings (the IP4 ones, not the hardware)) I have a situation I have never encountered before: the DNS resolution of some domains is not attempted at all on my Windows 10 laptop. Everything used to work "before".

*This is probably an advanced question, except if I missed something really obvious - I am just writing this to welcome any response, but also possibly more advanced ones*

**Details**: I own two domains (`mydomain1.com` and `mydomain2.com`), work from home (`mydomain2.com` is sent by my DHCP server) on a company laptop (which is part of an AD domain and has the default domain `company.com`).

What works:

- I can resolve external and my domains via `nslookup`
- software that uses the resolver library (the browser, `ping`, ... - I will use `ping` as an example later)

  - resolves any external domain (say, `google.com`)
  - **does not resolve neither of my domains**

Please note that `nslookup` resolves differently than `ping`: it hooks directly to the DNS server and does not go though the resolver library.

I checked (Wireshark) the traffic when attempting to access `mydomain1.com` or `mydomain2.com`: **there is no attempt to resolve the domain, ever**. This includes FQDNs that were never checked before (such as random `mlzejljrklfdjkhfdgjth.mydomain1.com`).

The configuration of the interfaces is

```
> ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : LP5-XXX1
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : company.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Peer-Peer
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : company.com
                                       mydomain2.com

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mydomain2.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Lenovo USB Ethernet #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 98-FA-9B-78-F7-8B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.11(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : dimanche 2 octobre 2022 10:16:56
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : dimanche 2 octobre 2022 11:16:56
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

I connected the laptop to an unrelated network (phone ISP) and tried to `ping jhfjdfhduyfjd.mydomain1.com` (new name), and again no DNS traffic in Wireshark.

Notes:

- all the other devices on my home network resolve all names (internal, external) without problems
- I was able to resolve everything before yesterday's investigation session
- the `hosts` file is empty except for `127.0.0.1` pointing to `localhost`
- the `ping` resolution fails on short FQDN (`aaa.mydomain1.com`) and ended ones (`aaa.mydomain1.com.` - note the dot at the end)
- I reset the TCP/IP stack via the commands below and rebooted several times

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
```

It is like if a setting on my laptop rejected/disregarded/filtered out attempts to resolve any of these domains. What is particularly strange is that it relates to both `mydomain1.com` and `mydomain2.com` domains - `mydomain1.com` is not used anywhere in the laptop configuration (`mydomain2.com` arrives though DHCP but that should not be a problem as it is for suffix resolution)

Thank, you for having read so far.

My question:

- either how to fully reset the networking on Windows 10
- or how to further investigate for that weird filtering

I have had my fair share of Windows issues over the last 30 years but here I am at loss. My ultimate "solution" will be to reinstall my laptop but I would really, really would like to avoid that :)

EDIT: a `ping somehost.mydomain1.com` started from WSL2 works OK.

Comment: Try the Network troubleshooter in *Settings > Network & Internet > Status*, then restart router and computer. ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-wi-fi-connection-issues-in-windows-9424a1f7-6a3b-65a6-4d78-7f07eee84d2c#WindowsVersion=Windows_10))

Comment: @harrymc: yes, I have tried all of that. I have restarted the router just in case too (a few times to start from scratch) but except if there was some special provision for the IP of my laptop (there are none) then why should that matter when all other devices resolve fine. I understand the "just in case because magic" part but outside of that the router should not be faulty.

Comment: The system DNS Client service does resolving and caching. Try to stop it in the Services applet and then `ping` (if it works without this service).

Comment: @harrymc: I cannot stop the DNS Client service (despite having admin rights) - a reboot would reset it but that's all.

Comment: Have you tried to go back to the last restore point?

Comment: @1NN unfortunately I do not have any useful (before yesterday)

Comment: The reboot problem can be solved, but does stopping the service help in any way?

Comment: @harrymc: sorry, I was not clear: the ability to modify the service whatsoever is grayed out, from an elevated prompt. `Get-Service 'DNS*'` shows the `Dnscache` service (= DNS Client), but stopping it is not possible (via `Stop-Service` or the GUI)

Comment: You can force-disable it through the registry - [link](https://wintechlab.com/enable-disable-dns-client-service/).

Comment: @harrymc: thank you. I disabled the service, rebooted, but the problem remains.

Comment: Are you sure the service was not running in spite of the changes? Without it, there is no local DNS cache, so this behavior is double-weird. Do you perhaps have some software installed that could cause this?

Comment: @harrymc: yes. I just did it again, to be extra super sure. The DNS Cashe is "Disabled". `ipconfig /displaydns` says "cannot display the DNS Resolver Cache". `ping somethingthatexists.mydomain1.com` fails with `Ping request could not find host`. `nslookup somethingthatexists.mydomain1.com`  is resolved correctly. I am in the office now, so this is the same behaviour on my network and elsewhere. This is I think the first time in 30 years I am really lost :) But this is Windows, so anything can happen (I am rather a linux guy)

Comment: @harrymc: I found the reason - thanks for your help, I discovered new things related to DNS in Windows on the way :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the source of the issue: it was an old *DirectAccess Name Resolution Policy* that managed `mydomain1.com` and `mydomain2.com`.

Removing the policies (UUID entries) from the registry below solved the problem

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters\DnsPolicyConfig
```

Now: why was that working before? there is a reason for that related to a GPO that changed bout the time I started to have the issue and that (probably - still need to confirm that) released DirectAccess (allowed me to use it), and it probably was not the case before.